# Adding integers to Multiplication Table

Tags: java, arrays

Using the command line command:

> > java *class* -table 7

is supposed to print a table:

```
 7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7
 7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16
 7     9    11    13    15    17    19    21    23    25
 7    10    13    16    19    22    25    28    31    34
 7    11    15    19    23    27    31    35    39    43
 7    12    17    22    27    32    37    42    47    52
 7    13    19    25    31    37    43    49    55    61
 7    14    21    28    35    42    49    56    63    70
 7    15    23    31    39    47    55    63    71    79
 7    16    25    34    43    52    61    70    79    88
```

which is a 10 x 10 multiplication table with "7" added to each number. 
In other words, it adds 7 to each number in the following table:

```
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
 0     2     4     6     8    10    12    14    16    18
 0     3     6     9    12    15    18    21    24    27
 0     4     8    12    16    20    24    28    32    36
 0     5    10    15    20    25    30    35    40    45
 0     6    12    18    24    30    36    42    48    54
 0     7    14    21    28    35    42    49    56    63
 0     8    16    24    32    40    48    56    64    72
 0     9    18    27    36    45    54    63    72    81
```

The following code is what I have so far. It prints out the original table starting at 0. However I do not understand how I am suppose to add `args[1]` to each value. (`args[1]` being 7 in the case above). How do I add `args[1]` to each value in the table?

I am also supposed to print "Argument count mismatch" if the user does not put exactly 1 `int` after `-table` in the command line.

For the code I have, it prints "Argument count mismatch" at the appropriate times, but it prints for all numbers, so it prints the line 100 times. I understand that I should put that part of the code outside of the loops, because I only want it to print once. How could I implement it to do that?

```
private static void table(String[] args) {
    int[][] table = new int[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (args.length != 2)
                System.out.println("Argument count mismatch");
            else
                System.out.printf("%6d", i * j);  
        }
        System.out.println();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have an upvote for a well-written first-ish question!

Comment: `I understand that I should put that part of the code outside of the loops` So put it outside of the loop... then add a `return;` statement inside the `if` to terminate the method. You already describe precisely what you  need to do.

Comment: But so if I print Argument code mismatch, I also do not want to print the chart. To print the chart (and refer to both i and j) I would need to put that inside the loop, yeah?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, well parse the second command line argument as an Int and add it to each value:

```
private static void table(String[] args) {
    int numToAdd = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int[][] table = new int[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%6d", i * j + numToAdd);  
        }
        System.out.println();
    } 
}
```

Not sure why you created a table double array, since you never use it.

And the output:

```
java Test -test 7
     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7
     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16
     7     9    11    13    15    17    19    21    23    25
     7    10    13    16    19    22    25    28    31    34
     7    11    15    19    23    27    31    35    39    43
     7    12    17    22    27    32    37    42    47    52
     7    13    19    25    31    37    43    49    55    61
     7    14    21    28    35    42    49    56    63    70
     7    15    23    31    39    47    55    63    71    79
     7    16    25    34    43    52    61    70    79    88
```

I would create a different method:

```
public static boolean validateArgs(String[]args){
   //all code to validate the args here.  
   //print validation specific errors here
}
```

Then your main:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    if(validateArgs(args)){
         table(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
private static void table(String[] args) {
    int[][] table = new int[10][10];
    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Argument count mismatch");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%6d", i * j + 7);  
        }
        System.out.println();
    }    
}
```

(If you don't prefer exit, use if...else instead.)

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much already answered yourself:

You should put the checking outside the loop. `args` does not change from number to number, there is not point to check it every time you need to add the number.

It would be a lot better to decompose the problem into 2 parts:

- Validate the arguments and find the number you need to add.
- Print the actual table with the number added.

After you have completed the first part, the second is trivial. You have some `int toAdd` with the number, so just print `i * j + toAdd` instead of `i * j`.

The first part is a bit more tricky:
You need to first verify the input, i.e. there are exactly 2 arguments and the second is a valid number. You also need to actually convert the `String` to a number. The checking number and conversion part can be done in one go via `Integer.parseInt()`.

Hence, the combined code, in shorthand:

```
if (args.length != 2) {
    System.out.println("Argument count mismatch");
    return;
}
int toAdd;
try {
    toAdd = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Second argument is not a number!");
    return;
}

// Your modified loop goes here
```